# HTML Video Not Playing Audio

Tags: html, html5-video, html5-audio

I am trying to play an mp4 file I have stored locally on my computer (when I play it with quicktime it works perfectly). For some reason however I can't get it to work with sound. If I include the 'muted' keyword, the mp4 plays, however with no sound (makes sense). However if I remove the 'muted' keyword, it doesn't play at all.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<video id="introVideo" width="50%" height="100%" autoplay loop muted>
  <source src="../static/myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little late, but starting in Chrome 66 autoplay doesn't work unless the muted attribute is included.

So in Chrome you can autoplay a muted video or autoplay won't work.

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-autoplay

Edit:
https://blog.chromium.org/2018/03/chrome-66-beta-css-typed-object-model.html

Search for 'autoplay' in the chromium blog link.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with another web browser? Because autoplay is not allowed and even more on sounds with Chrome

Comment: tried it with chrome and safari. same outcome. i have used autoplay with chrome before with no issues - and that part is working. i just cant get the audio to work

Comment: The problem is the autoplay->sound with HTML it's working with IE Mozilla but not on Chrome i had the same problem, you'll be able with JS to make it work but with only HTML never had a solution.